# Як правильно писати, поп-корн чи попкорн?

Tags: разом-дефіс-окремо

Так, здебільшого у Ґуґлі вискакує інформація, де пишемо попкорн. Проте ще знайшла на сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/popkorn), що варіантами написання є popcorn, поп-корн, однак в академічних виданнях, наприклад, СУМ-11, це слово взагалі не фіксується.

То як правильно записувати це слово?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У [Словнику англіцизмів](http://slovopedia.org.ua/46/53407/302207.html) знаходимо:

> **ПОПКОРН** 
>   л.н.а. *«підсмажені зерна кукурудзи»*.

У [Вікіпедіїї](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD) також:

> **Попкорн** (баранці, бахканці, повітряна кукурудза, англ. popcorn)

Мовою оригіналу **popcorn** пишеться разом, тому і лексичне запозичення цілком логічно зберігає особливості правопису.

У [ПРИКМЕТНИКОВІ ДЕРИВАТИ ВІД НОВІТНІХ ЗАПОЗИЧЕНЬ
У СУЧАСНИХ УКРАЇНСЬКИХ ЗМІ Е. Е. Мінкевич](http://dspace.onu.edu.ua:8080/handle/123456789/9202) також бачимо написання **попкорн**.

Отже, з вищенаведеного можна (зважаючи особливо на посилання *словника*) зробити висновок, що правильно вживати **попкорн**.